# Convenient way to see what's new in remote repositories?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-status

In Git, I'd like to be able to see, at a glance, whether my repository and working directory are out of date. I often make the mistake of just running "git status" - but that doesn't do any remote communication at all. Or, I'll do this:

```
git fetch --all
git status
```

But that doesn't show activity on other branches.

What's a good, convenient way to get information like:

1. Are there updates to this branch in any remote repository?
2. Are there updates to any parent branch?
3. Have any new branches been made - who by, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get "who by" since branch creation is not actually recorded anywhere.  (You can find who owns the most recent commits on a given branch, but, e.g., if the branch was created as synonymous with another branch, the commits often have nothing to do with "who created it".  For instance if I do `git push origin master:newbranch` then the branch I just created on the remote has, as its most recent commit, the same most-recent commit as `master`, which is not necessarily "mine".)

The output from `git fetch --all` does show activity by default, though.  For instance:

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Fetching rohan
From [redacted]
   55f37f2..dc439fc  master     -> rohan/master
```

This says that I've just updated my idea of rohan/master based on stuff I brought over from the remote I named "rohan".  Nothing was updated in origin/*.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `gitk --all`. This will start a graphical interface displaying all local and remote branches. In console mode, I am using the following git alias:

```
graph = log --graph --all --decorate --oneline
```

But beware, working directory is not to be confused with branches... What I just said is true for looking at branches, but changes in the working directory (so, uncommited stuff) is completely different, and shown by `git status` as you said.